# Printing data to text file

Tags: matlab, printf

I am using the `fprintf` command to store the contents of a `.mat` file to a `.txt`. The `.mat` file contains strings. My code prints the data in the same column.

```
fid = fopen('exp.txt','wt');
for i=1:275
    fprintf (fid,classes{i}{1})
end
fclose(fid);
```

When I use the  `\n` and the '\r\n' options, they doesn't print anything to the file. I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: which editor you using to look at the printed file? did you try using word?

Comment: try opening the file in MS word. I had this problem once before, where some editors will not display '\n'.

Comment: Even better option is to try reading back the file and see if it has those new line chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some text editors will show those new line characters and some wont. This happens because of different standards followed by different softwares and operating systems for eg:

```
end of line sequences
Windows end of line sequence:  \r\n
Unix end of line sequence: \n
Mac end of line sequence: \r
```

So if you really want good human readable formats, either fix your operation system/software and use characters friendly for that system, or if you want uniformity in the reports, better write files in standard HTML formats :) 
adding a "br" tag and naming file .html is as simple as writing out '\n' and naming it .txt!

Comment: I tried `\r\n` but it still doesn't show up on `notepad` which is essentially what I wanted, but somehow word manages to open it even without the '\r\n'

Comment: if you absolutely must be able to read it in notepad, you can do a simple experiment which should take only about minutes. Write a couple of sentences in notepad in different lines. Read that file from the matlab and see what new line character is used in notepad.